# function not returning value and instead returning object in protractor with javascript

Tags: javascript, protractor

My code snippet

```
getitemsCount:function (css) {
    return element(by.deepCss(css));
},
getCount:function(){
    return this.getitemsCount('span.summary').getText().then(function (text) {
        return text;
    })
},
```

able to print text value to console but not returning .
any help is appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: this is not a duplicate i believe

Comment: How are you implementing / using this code in your script. As far as I can see there is nothing wrong with this part

Comment: I am calling getCount and trying to use this value for another step. like console.log("counts:"+getCount()) . I do not want to do any promises using except